# World Bank API query

Tags: r, api

I want to get data using World Bank's API. For this purpose I use follow query.

```
wb_data <- httr::GET("http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/all/indicator/AG.AGR.TRAC.NO?format=json") %>%
      content("text", encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
      fromJSON(flatten = T)  %>%
      data.frame()
```

It works pretty good. However, when I try to specify more than two variables it doesn't work.

```
http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/all/indicator/AG.AGR.TRAC.NO;NE.CON.PRVT.ZS?format=json
```

Note, if i change format to `xml` and also add `source=2` because data become from same database (World Development Indicator) query works.

```
http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/all/indicator/AG.AGR.TRAC.NO;NE.CON.PRVT.ZS?source=2&formal=xml
```

However, if i want to get data from different databases (e.g. WDI and Doing Business) it doesn't work again.

So, my first question is how can I get multiple data from different databases using one query. According to the [World Bank API tutorial](https://datahelpdesk.worldbank.org/knowledgebase/articles/1886674-new-features-and-enhancements-in-the-v2-api) I can include about 60 indicators.

My second question is how can I specify number of rows per page. As I might know I can add something like `&per_page=100` to get 100 rows as an output. Should i calculate number of rows by myself or I can use something lika that `&per_page=9999999` to get all data upon request.

P.S. I don't want to use any libraries (such as: *wb* or *wbstats*). I want to do it by myself and also to learn something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer to your question. To use multiple indicators and return JSON, you need to provide **both** the source ID and the format type, as mentioned in the World Bank API tutorial. You can get the total number of pages from one of the returned JSON parameters, called "total". You can then use this value in a second GET request to return the full number of pages using the `per_page` parameter.

```r
library(magrittr)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

# set up the target url - you need BOTH the source ID and the format parameters
target_url <- "http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/chn;ago/indicator/AG.AGR.TRAC.NO;SP.POP.TOTL?source=2&format=json"

# look at the metadata returned for the target url
httr::GET(target_url) %>%
    content("text", encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
    fromJSON(flatten = T) %>% 
    # the metadata is in the first item in the returned list of JSON
    extract2(1)
#> $page
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $pages
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $per_page
#> [1] 50
#> 
#> $total
#> [1] 240
#> 
#> $sourceid
#> NULL
#> 
#> $lastupdated
#> [1] "2019-12-20"

# get the total number of pages for the target url query
wb_data_totalpagenumber <- httr::GET(target_url) %>%
    content("text", encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
    fromJSON(flatten = T) %>% 
    # get the first item in the returned list of JSON
    extract2(1) %>% 
    # get the total number of pages, which is a named element called "total"
    extract2("total")

# get the data
wb_data <- httr::GET(paste0(target_url, "&per_page=", wb_data_totalpagenumber)) %>%
    content("text", encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
    fromJSON(flatten = T) %>% 
    # get the data, which is the second item in the returned list of JSON
    extract2(2) %>% 
    data.frame()

# look at the data
dim(wb_data)
#> [1] 240  11

head(wb_data)
#>   countryiso3code date value scale unit obs_status decimal   indicator.id
#> 1             AGO 2019    NA                             0 AG.AGR.TRAC.NO
#> 2             AGO 2018    NA                             0 AG.AGR.TRAC.NO
#> 3             AGO 2017    NA                             0 AG.AGR.TRAC.NO
#> 4             AGO 2016    NA                             0 AG.AGR.TRAC.NO
#> 5             AGO 2015    NA                             0 AG.AGR.TRAC.NO
#> 6             AGO 2014    NA                             0 AG.AGR.TRAC.NO
#>                    indicator.value country.id country.value
#> 1 Agricultural machinery, tractors         AO        Angola
#> 2 Agricultural machinery, tractors         AO        Angola
#> 3 Agricultural machinery, tractors         AO        Angola
#> 4 Agricultural machinery, tractors         AO        Angola
#> 5 Agricultural machinery, tractors         AO        Angola
#> 6 Agricultural machinery, tractors         AO        Angola

tail(wb_data)
#>     countryiso3code date     value scale unit obs_status decimal indicator.id
#> 235             CHN 1965 715185000  <NA>                       0  SP.POP.TOTL
#> 236             CHN 1964 698355000  <NA>                       0  SP.POP.TOTL
#> 237             CHN 1963 682335000  <NA>                       0  SP.POP.TOTL
#> 238             CHN 1962 665770000  <NA>                       0  SP.POP.TOTL
#> 239             CHN 1961 660330000  <NA>                       0  SP.POP.TOTL
#> 240             CHN 1960 667070000  <NA>                       0  SP.POP.TOTL
#>       indicator.value country.id country.value
#> 235 Population, total         CN         China
#> 236 Population, total         CN         China
#> 237 Population, total         CN         China
#> 238 Population, total         CN         China
#> 239 Population, total         CN         China
#> 240 Population, total         CN         China
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Good job, Sir. It works, however, my first problem remains unsolved, is it possible to include some variables from different databases (sources)? I tried to use ```?source=1``` and also ```?source=1&source=2``` but it doesn't work

Comment: Ah I thought you wanted to use different indicators. You mean you want to use more than one source ID? I don't think that's possible with the current JSON returning API. You might have to do multiple calls and then `rbind` your results.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry, but I have another one question. Let assume that I have six indicators which I want to extract for all existed countries for the last 30 years. Using previous code I find out that this database will contain 47,5k rows. When I try to send query it return me an error .... ```lexical error: invalid char in json text. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="u (right here)```. If i change time period from 2000 to 2019 (31,7k rows) it works. As far as I can understand there is a limitation for the row number?

Comment: Might be better to post that as a new question with your example code that throws this error.